# Dynamic Nuxt Img as background image not working with Nuxt Static Site Generation

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, static-site

[`nuxt-img`](https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/get-started/) currently works for me for [full static site generation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/commands/generate#nuxi-generate) except when I have the image source passed in as props and render it as a background-image using [`useImage()`](https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/api/dollarimg). It kind of works in dev (images are shown, but always all full resolution of the raw image) but not at all once generated. I am using the default [ipx](https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/providers/introduction#default-provider) provider with images hosted locally in `public` folder and all webp format.

package.json

```json
"devDependencies": {
  "@nuxt/image-edge": "^1.0.0-28004510.a0dc8e8",
  "nuxt": "^3.3.2"
}
```

script

```js
const $img = useImage()
const imgUrl = $img(props.image, 'sm:100vw md:100vw lg:100vw xl:100vw')
```

template

```js
<div :style="`background-image: url('${imgUrl}')`" />
```

parent component

```js
<travel-log-section v-for="place in travelLogData" v-bind="place" />
```

nuxt.config.ts

```
modules: ['@nuxt/image-edge'],
image: {
    dir: 'public/images',
    screens: {
        sm: 640,
        md: 1024,
        lg: 1920,
        xl: 2280,
        },
    },
```

After running `yarn generate && yarn preview` all the other images (using `nuxt-img` but not as a `background-image`) work, but these ones all return 404.

```
 HTTP  4/23/2023 12:14:37 PM 127.0.0.1 GET /_ipx/_/travel-log/skopje.webp
 HTTP  4/23/2023 12:14:37 PM 127.0.0.1 Returned 404 in 2 ms
 HTTP  4/23/2023 12:14:37 PM 127.0.0.1 GET /_ipx/_/travel-log/ohrid.webp
 HTTP  4/23/2023 12:14:37 PM 127.0.0.1 Returned 404 in 2 ms
```

The [`nuxt-img` site](https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/advanced/static-images/) says "Static Image support is under progress for Nuxt 3", but is that really the problem (because support for both static generation and `useImage` are marked as done in [the official github discussion](https://github.com/nuxt/image/discussions/548)), or is something else causing the crawler not to get to these images?